# is it a good practice to use nullptr as None as in python in c++

Tags: c++, class, nullptr

I'm building a program with c++, but I'm not sure if this way is right.

```
class A {
  private:
    unsigned *a;

    bool checkA() {
      return a != nullptr;
    }

  public:
    A() {
      this->a = nullptr;
    }

    void setA(unsigned a) {
      this->a = new unsigned(a);
    }
}
```

The member variable 'a' will only be set by 'setA', however in other method, I have to check if 'a' has been set. Thus I used nullptr to check if it is set.

Is this code a good practice?

I tried to change the datatype of 'a' to int and set it to -1 to notice for an uninitialized value. However I think there would be a better way to do this.

Please give me some advices.

Comment: `std::optional`

Comment: For _any other type_ I would also champion `std::optional`, but for pointers `nullptr` is actually designed to work as such by the language. The real trick is proper initialization. In your class, make sure _all_ constructor paths initialize `a` to either a valid address or `nullptr`. Or, better yet, use a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: In general in C++ don't use pointers if you dont have to. Your member variable a should just be an `unsigned int`. Try to limit the use of new/delete too.  Just a reminder C++ is NOTHING like python (except some concepts like for loops). Memory is managed in a totally different manner, and starts with learning about C++ scopes. `{ }`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I have been trying to find!

Comment: initialize your variables when you declare them.  `unsigned* a{ nullptr };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::optional<int>` if you really want.

But `setA` itself is an anti-pattern, just set the value in the constructor, RAII is your friend, not something to actively avoid.

It is much easier to reason about the code if `a` is always present than  `A` being stateful with sometimes having `a`, sometimes not.